# how to return a phys_addr_t type value to user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need my driver to return `phys_addr_t` type value through an `ioctl` call. I need to return this value through a struct which is passed through `arg`. The question is what type do I use in this struct?

For example, say the following struct is passed through an arg

```
struct myStruct {
  int input1;
  char input2;
  <type> physAddr;
} ;


someStruct.physAddr = virt_to_phys(virtAddr);
```

`virt_to_phys` returns a `phys_addr_t`, however this type doesn't seem to exist in any of the standard includes. So my question is what type do I need to use in user space for `phys_addr_t`?

Comment: Physical addresses are meaningless outside the kernel.

Comment: @Barmar I know. But that's not the question I was asking. The question still stands, what type I need to use in user space or what I need to include into my file in order to see the value of `physAddr`?

Comment: `unsigned long`? http://man.cx/virt_to_phys%289%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the full kernel source, in `include/linux/types.h` we have:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_PHYS_ADDR_T_64BIT
typedef u64 phys_addr_t;
#else
typedef u32 phys_addr_t;
#endif
```

So, to be safe, just use `u64`.

Note that this definition is removed from `/usr/include/linux/types.h`.

However, if you are writing a custom utility that interacts with a custom device and its custom driver, it is okay to skip the `/usr/include` versions and build directly against the version in (e.g.) `/usr/src/kernel/...`).

This is not recommended for regular programs [of course]. But, if you are doing a hybrid system that has a lot of things going between the utility and the driver, you can craft it any way you'd like.

For example, a realtime hidef video encoding platform I wrote code for did this. The driver sent data to the device. The device sent data back. The data was sent to the utility/control program which modified the data and sent it back, etc. This was all done with a *lot* of custom `ioctl` calls, so we could do whatever was required.

Answer (score 1):

It's either 32 or 64 bits, unsigned.  See here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L161

You could probably use `intptr_t` to some extent, but I would be concerned if you end up running on a system with 32-bit Linux on 64-bit hardware.

Comment: ...or a system with 32-bit Linux on 32-bit hardware with physical address extensions and all the memory above the 4GB boundary ([if you think I'm joking...](http://www.ti.com/product/66AK2H14)).